# How to make event pass through visible DOM element

Tags: javascript, events, dom, layout

Let us have this code:

```
<div id="outer_container">
  <div id="inner_child_1"></div>
  <div id="inner_child_2"></div>
</div>

div#outer_container
{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

div#inner_child_1
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

div#inner_child_2
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

When we make a click, for example, on the top layer inner_child_2, the event will propagate to all event handlers registered to inner_child_2 and its parent outer_container. Not to inner_child_1 despite it is directly below inner_child_2. This is by specification. All modern browsers do it.

My question is this:

How to make an event pass through inner_child_2 and reach inner_child_1, besides making inner_child_1 not visible or change its z-index?
(Or transparent, but this will only work in IE8)

I thought about triggering an event myself in some handler code registered to inner_child_2. But in the real usage case, I don't know where to dispatch the event, as below inner_child_2, there are multiple elements laid out in unpredictable fashion and I want each one to receive events as if inner_child_2 was not there. Ideally, I want to be able to selectively let some events pass while keeping others out.

I know this is a difficult question, but I will appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to take a bottom-up approach:

In the parent container, you would handle the `click` event, then iterate through its children and compare the click's coordinates with the relative bounds of each child. If the click is within the bounds, a click should have been triggered there, so manually trigger a `click` event on that child.

Comment: Of course I will have to evaluate children visible status, z-index and maybe other fun stuff. And how do I know if the child even has event handler of the appropriate type registered?

Comment: I think that if the child's event isn't registered, it will be ignored. Don't you want to handle regardless of z-index? Finally, you would have to check visible status, but that shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a solution that does not include reimplementing half the browser :) Maybe there is none? I will have to research more, but the part with comparing coordinates with bounds seems very complex.